# Activerecord find parents that do not have any children with a certain field value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to find all parent records that do not have any children with a certain field value. I was hoping this would work:

```
results = Parent.joins(:children).where.not('children.field' => "some_field_value")
```

But it returns all parents that have ANY children that do not have a field that equals "some_field_value".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not the cleanest solution, but you can first find parents that have any children *with* that certain field value, and then get the inverse.

```
inverse = Child.where(field: 'some_field_value').pluck(:parent_id).uniq
results = Parent.where.not(id: inverse)
```

Comment: If you say `inverse = Child.where(field: '...').select(:parent_id)` and then `Parent.where.not(id: inverse)` you'll get a subquery and let the database do the work.